# Generating sublist of list given strings

Tags: c#, linq

I am very new to LINQ and am wondering if there is a way to extract a sublist from a list of strings given that the string values are provided beforehand.

For example, if I have:

```
var movies = new List<Movie>
{
    new Movie { Name = "Noah" },
    new Movie { Name = "Terminator" },
    new Movie { Name = "Troy" },
    new Movie { Name = "Gladiator" },
};
```

I would like to use LINQ to create a sublist if I provide the Name strings "Noah" and "Troy".

I have tried googling and results point me to SelectMany and GroupBy but all of the examples involve lists that contains primitive values, not primitives values contained in objects.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Just a `List<Movie>` that contains `Movie`s with the `Name` property matching the list of strings you pass in?

Comment: movies is not a list of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Linq lambda it would be:

```
var result = movies.where(x => x.Name == "Troy" || x.Name == "Noah");
```

This would return a `IEnumerable<Movie>` containing the ones searched for using `Where`.

Comment: Literally it doesn't return `List<Movie>` but  `IEnumerable<Movie>`

Comment: This works! Spent so many hours trying to solve it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var sublistItems = new List<string>() {"Noah", "Troy"} ;
var subList = movies.where(m=> sublistItems.Contains(m.Name));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var newlist = from m in movies
              where (m.Name == "Troy" || m.Name == "Noah")
              select m;
```